# How to repeat a set of codes in C program?

Tags: c

I want to repeat a set of command in my C program. This will depend on the number that the user enters. For example: if user enters 3, the codes inside the while loop I have will repeat 3 times. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

    int num1,i,num2,num3;

    printf("Enter your number:");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    num1 = i;

    while (i < num1) {
            printf("Enter days");
            scanf("%d", &num1);

            printf("Hello World");
            printf("Bye World");
    }
}
```

When I run the program it just asks me the number to enter and then the program ends.

Comment: You are not initializing variable `i` anywhere in your code (and even if you did, the condition `i < num1` could not be true when you set `num1 = i`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num1 = i;
```

`i` is just declared not initialized and you compare it in loop-

```
while (i < num1) {
```

Initialize `i` and then use it .

What you wrote in question and what you did is little confusion , but to make it work -

```
  i=0;
  //num1=i;               I didn't get these parts so commented it 
  while (i < num1) {             //you loop will run now
       // printf("Enter days");       // these also didn't get it either
        //scanf("%d", &num1);

        printf("Hello World");
        printf("Bye World");
        i++;
 }
```

Comment: While this answer is *fast*, it doesn't address the real issue, that the `scanf()`'d value for `num1` is overwritten.

Comment: `i` will also need to be incremented inside of the while loop.

Comment: @jchamp  I don't why he really write it like that . But I just modified to work , for number of input times.

Comment: @EOF Yeah didn't really know what was done there .Even if not over-written loop wouldn't work . But made loop to work atleast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop if you want, but using a `for` loop might make more sense and reduce the amount of code you need to write. I think that in this case the following would be reasonable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int num1, i;

    printf("Enter your number:");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    for(i = 0 ; i < num1 ; ++i) {
            printf("Hello World");
    }

    printf("Bye World");
}
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = i;
while (i < num1) {
```

How it is possible, while condition will be false always. It should be like

```
i = 0;
while (i < num1) {
```

Rest all looks good.